# IIS rewrite - redirect path to a different URL, including partial path (C# web config)

Tags: url, redirect, iis, url-rewriting, config

I have a multisite setup in Sitecore, where my main site is mysite.com and I have a secondary site of secondsite.org. These both work, but the user can also navigate to secondsite.org by going to the Sitecore path for the second site home node, i.e. mysite.com/second-site-home. I don't want this to happen, so I added a redirect in the webconfig so that mysite.com/second-site-home will redirect to secondsite.org:

```
<rule name="homepage path Redirect" stopProcessing="true">
  <match url="^second-site-home/?(.*)$" />
  <action type="Redirect" url="http://secondsite.org" redirectType="Found"/>
  <conditions>
    <add input="{HTTP_HOST}" pattern="^(www\.)?mysite.com$" />
  </conditions>
</rule>
```

This works fine for the homepage, but I have links on mysite.com that go to pages on secondsite.org, and these links are rendering as mysite.com/second-site-home/about, and when I navigate to this link I get redirected to the secondsite homepage, rather than the actual page I want to go to.

Is is possible to modify the redirect so that in the redirect url, it includes the rest of the path *after* /second-site-home/ ?

Answer (score 0):

You just need to add a back reference variable to your rule:

```
<rule name="homepage path Redirect" stopProcessing="true">
  <match url="^second-site-home/?(.*)$" />
  <action type="Redirect" url="http://secondsite.org/{R:1}" redirectType="Found"/>
  <conditions>
    <add input="{HTTP_HOST}" pattern="^(www\.)?mysite.com$" />
  </conditions>
</rule>
```